# Font size confusion in LaTeX

Tags: authblk

I am a beginner in LaTeX and I am not able to resolve the problem. Hopefully, I will get the help here.

I have the following code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
 \usepackage{authblk}
 \renewcommand{\Authfont}{\fontsize{12}{14.4pt}\selectfont}
 \renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}
 \begin{document}
\title{\textbf{Preparation of Papers for IEEE Sponsored Conferences \& Symposia}}
\author{Navdeep Singh\textsuperscript{a}, Lakhwinder Kaur \textsuperscript{b}, Kuldeep Singh \textsuperscript{c}}
\affil[a,b]{Dept. of Computer Science \& Engg., Punjabi University, Patiala, 147001, Punjab}
\affil[c]{Bharat Electronics Ltd, Ghaziabad, U.P, India}
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

and it gives the following output:
[image]

Here as we can observe the superscript on the last author's name contains an unwanted '1'. I am not able to find out what is the mistake in my code. Please help me locate it.

Another question I would like to ask is based on the following 2 commands

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\Authfont}{\fontsize{12}{14.4pt}\selectfont}
```

Both the commands say that the font size is 12pt then why is the font size of title and authors different? I know they both belong to different packages but a given font size of 12pt should remain the same? Isn't it right?

What if I am told by the journal to use a font size of 12pt, how can I be sure which one is right to use. Please advise me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You asked, "[W]hy is the font size of title and authors different?" Why do you believe that setting a document font size of 12pt makes the title font size equal to 12pt?

Comment: Thanks! As we have assigned the default font size of the whole document to be 12pt, so I think font size of title should also be 12pt. Btw what is the default size of title?

Comment: The "default font size for the whole document" is generally understood to be the font size for running or "ordinary" text. Titles and sectioning headers are generally typeset in a larger font -- no doubt in order to make these document elements "stand out", visually speaking. In the standard LaTeX document classes, the relative font size for *titles* -- more precisely, the material contained in the argument of `\title` -- is generally `\LARGE` (ca. 1.7x linear magnification relative to `\normalsize`). If you want to deviate from this convention, you need to do so explicitly.

Comment: Real thanks for such a nice explanation Mico.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set the footnotemarker with the optional argument of \author:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,lipsum}
 \usepackage{authblk}
 \renewcommand{\Affilfont}{\footnotesize}
 \renewcommand{\Authfont}{\normalsize}
 \renewcommand\Authands{, }
 \begin{document}
\title{\textbf{Preparation of Papers for IEEE Sponsored Conferences \& Symposia}}
\author[a]{Navdeep Singh}
\author[b]{Lakhwinder Kaur}
\author[c]{Kuldeep Singh}
\affil[a,b]{Dept. of Computer Science \& Engg., Punjabi University, Patiala, 147001, Punjab}
\affil[c]{Bharat Electronics Ltd, Ghaziabad, U.P, India}
\date{}
\maketitle

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The title is larger than 12pt.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation. As I am new to LaTeX, I am curious to know why the earlier method failed? How can we decide which is a better method as I now think there are multiple ways to perform something in LaTeX.

Comment: and how do we make the superscript 'a' inside the [a] of \author[a]{Navdeep Singh} bold?